# TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I am using this module for authorize.net payment gateway :-
https://github.com/durango/authorize-net-cim

I am getting an error, while calling the following method :-

```
    throw err;
              ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Code :

```
AuthorizeCIM.updateCustomerProfile(new Authorize.CustomerBasic({
        email: 'brocklesnar@brockkkk.com',
        merchantCustomerId: 1234,
        description: 'New description!',
        customerProfileId: 23954000
    }), function(err, response) {});
```

AuthorizeCIM is perfectly connecting with authorize.net as i can create profiles.

I am following the exact documentation, but still getting the error.

Can anybody figure out, what is happening?

Comment: It got solved. There was a problem in `Authorize` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

if `CustomerBasic` is an instance method, then the code should be

```
AuthorizeCIM.updateCustomerProfile((new Authorize).CustomerBasic({
    email: 'brocklesnar@brockkkk.com',
    merchantCustomerId: 1234,
    description: 'New description!',
    customerProfileId: 23954000
}), function(err, response) {});
```